# SQL Server database deleted but still contain table structures?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I have deleted my database and checked the directory where the database files were originally stored and the files have disappeared.

If I now do "New Database" from SQL Server Management Studio with the same name as the deleted database expecting it to be empty, I find the tables from the deleted database still exist.

So my question is, how can the tables exist in my new database which has the same name as the database that I deleted?

Comment: Check your `model` database. Are the tables in there?

Comment: Restart SSMS. SSMS caches some state. Probably you are seeing stale cached data.

Comment: As suggested by others u need to restart ssms . else the other way round to check whether the table is present or not is using the query SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables

Comment: How are you "finding the tables"?

Comment: In sql server management console, when I create the database, I click the tables folder and there tables are shown (with data in them).

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, the tables are present in the Model database. I must have run a script in the pass and the model database must have been set as the context. I will delete them. Why were the tables present when I created the database? In other words, how did the model database affect the creation of database?

Comment: Are you using a DELETE command (which only removes the data) or a DROP TABLE command (which removes the entire table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a database, SQL Server uses the `model` database as a template.  The `model` database is copied and then renamed to the new database.

Perhaps the `model` database contains some of the tables.  To verify this theory, examine the `model` database under "System Databases".

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was that the tables were in the model database (and the master database).